# How is DDoS different from DRDoS?

Tags: denial-of-service, ddos

I understand DDoS is a DoS assault from multiple sources, where a coordinated stream of requests is launched against a target.

How is DRDoS different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To put it straight and simple, **DDOS** is is making the server unavailable or denying the service to the users for a particular time.

**DRDOS** is sending **forged requests** *imitating* the target (victim) to millions of computers and making the target **flooded** by the responses from those computers.

---

### More info on DRDOS

The attacker sends the requests from his server. Using IP address spoofing, the source address is set to that of the targeted victim, which means all the replies will go to (and flood) the target.

Comment: "Sending *from* a target" - Does that mean the forged requests came from the server (since servers are usual victims)?

Comment: The request does not really originate from the target, but the other machines think it does, so that's where they send their responses.

Comment: @ohtph There lies the trick. The attacker sends the requests from his server. Using IP address spoofing, the source address is set to that of the targeted victim, which means all the replies will go to (and flood) the target. I have also updated it in my answer. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @j__m exactly !

Comment: Exactly the same principle as if I set my 'reply to' address to bill.gates@microsoft.com and then send a load of emails out, replies will go to him.  Not that he works there anymore, but old habits die hard ;)

Comment: @Ebenezar - Just to be a bit more pedantic, I would add to your phrase "DDOS is is making the server unavailable or denying the service to the users for a particular time [with requests coming from multiple sources, as opposed to a DoS, which usually means one source of attack]."